# setListAdapter is not working properly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, baseadapter

I'm having a trouble for using a 'baseAdapter' to fill a 'fragmentList'.

I'm trying to show a list with all the musics stored in my device using 'MediaStore.Audio.Media', but the problem is when the program calls the function setListAdapter. If the number of items into the baseAdapter is a little large, only a part of the list is correctly filled.

The baseAdapter code:

```
public class MListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static final Integer KEY_LAYOUT_TITLE = 0;
public static final Integer KEY_LAYOUT_SUBTITLE = 1;
public static final Integer KEY_LAYOUT_OTHERS = 2;
public static final Integer KEY_LAYOUT_IMAGE_ID = 3;
public static final Integer KEY_LAYOUT_LIST = 4;

private ArrayList<String> arrayString;

private LayoutInflater lInflater = null;    
private Context context;

public MListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> arrString){

    context = ctx;
    arrayString = arrString;

    lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

}

public int getCount() {
    return arrayString.size();
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    return arrayString.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
       mView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_music_list, null);
       TextView mTitle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.musicNameTextView);
       //TextView mSubtitle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.musicArtistAlbumTextView);
       //TextView mOthers = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.musicDurationTextView);
       //ImageView mImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImageView);


       mTitle.setText(getItem(position));
       Log.d("DEBUG",String.valueOf(position));
       Log.d("DEBUG",String.valueOf(getCount()));


       //mSubtitle.setText(hashItem.get(KEY_LAYOUT_SUBTITLE));
       //mOthers.setText(hashItem.get(KEY_LAYOUT_OTHERS));

    }
    return mView;
}
```

The FragmentList:

```
public class MListFragment extends ListFragment {

MListFragmentListener mCallback;
InterfaceFragmentMusic typeMusicCallback;

// --- Global Variables
static ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>> mapString = null;
static ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Long>> mapImage = null;

// ---The URIs used to get a group of music and its informations
Uri uriMedias = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

/**
 * ---The following vectors of strings are used to choose what kind of
 * information will be retrieved from the database in each case (the
 * columns)
 */

final String[] columnsMedias = { 
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, 
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, 
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION

};

// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can
// deliver messages
public interface MListFragmentListener {
    /**
     * Called by MListFragment when a list item is selected It has been
     * implemented in the FragMusicActivity class!
     **/
    public void onMusicSelected(String musicName);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // The system initially shows the list with all the musics
    updateMList(MusicTypeFragment.KEY_POSITION_ALLSONGS);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected
    // list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is
    // available.)
    //if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.music_fragment) != null) {
    //  getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    //}
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (MListFragmentListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement MListFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}

/**
 * This fragment will be updated/refreshed whatever the user choose a music
 * option on the menu (on the left side)
 **/

/* It refreshes/updates the current list with a new type */
public void updateMList(int position) {
    Cursor cursor;
    MListAdapter mAdapter = null;

    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    cursor = cr.query(uriMedias, columnsMedias, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> arrString = new ArrayList<String>();

    populateMap(cursor, arrString);     
    mAdapter = new MListAdapter(getActivity(),arrString);


    int a = mAdapter.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        Log.d("MLISTFRAG", mAdapter.getItem(i));
    }


    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

     cursor.close();
}

/*
 * It populates an arrayList with the information about the musics using the
 * data passed by a cursor
 */
private void populateMap(Cursor c, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>> array,   ArrayList<String> arrString) {

    Cursor mCursor = c;
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        // Values by default
        //map.put(MListAdapter.KEY_LAYOUT_TITLE,
        //      getString(R.string.inBlank));
        //map.put(MListAdapter.KEY_LAYOUT_SUBTITLE,
        //      getString(R.string.inBlank));
        //map.put(MListAdapter.KEY_LAYOUT_OTHERS,
        //      getString(R.string.inBlank));

        // New values
        map.put(MListAdapter.KEY_LAYOUT_TITLE,
                mCursor.getString(MListAdapter.KEY_LAYOUT_TITLE));

        arrString.add(mCursor.getString(MListAdapter.KEY_LAYOUT_TITLE));
        array.add(map);
    }
    mCursor.close();
}
```

The results of these codes are that it's showed a list partially correct, I mean the first half of the list is okay, but the second half is the repetition of the first part.
I put a Log.d into the getView (in the baseAdapter) to verify if the the size of the array is correct and how many times the setListAdapter calls this method and the results (only to exemplify) are:

--> size = 30

--> how many times the method is called: 16

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not recycle the view properly.
In the getView method you only affect the TextView when the convertView is null. You need to update the TextView every time. Like this :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mView = convertView;

    if (mView == null) {
       mView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_music_list, null);
    }
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.musicNameTextView);
    mTitle.setText(getItem(position));

    return mView;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in to the getView! It works like a charm!
Thanks! =D